# Google Maps API - JavaScript: Finding elevation for given LatLng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone see any problems with my function?
I call the function like so:

```
 var elevation = getElevation(tempWaypt);
```

tempWaypt is a LatLng Object Literal, and it keeps telling me that

```
 elevation
```

is undefined!

```
 function getElevation(location) {
            elevator.getElevationForLocations({
                'locations': [location]
              }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK')
                        {
                            if (results[0])
                            {
                                  return results[0].elevation;
                            }
                        }
                  });
            }
```

Im using the function to determine if the LatLng is on land, or in sea!
Also, when ever I set a variable in the getElevation function equal to:

```
 results[0].elevation
```

It gives me the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Google Maps API services are asynchronous. Should you want to access the result, you could do but not limited to the following way, or using a Promise.

```
var elevation;
function getElevation(location) {
    ..., function(results, status) {
      ...
      if (results[0]) {
         elevation = results[0];
      }
  ...
}
```

Using a Promise

```js
getElevation.then(function(elevation){
  console.log("Elevation: " + elevation); 
});

function getElevation(location) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //...
    function(results, status) {
      //...
      if (results[0]) {
         resolve(results[0]);
      } else {
        reject('Your reason ...');
      }
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Might sound stupid, but how do you write that promise? Can't really get my head around it from the stuff i've seen online

Answer (score 0):

Elevation can be a tricky way to figure out if a point is on water or land because many dry places on earth exist at or below sea level. You may want to get a more *explicit* answer using a data source that deals specifically with water.

I work for a company that offers a free web API to determine if points are on water or land. We use it internally. It is called [onwater.io](https://onwater.io) and it is fairly straight forward: given a latitude and longitude it will accurately return true or false via a get request.

Example on water:
https://api.onwater.io/23.92323,-66.3

```
{
  lat: 23.92323,
  lon: -66.3,
  water: true
}
```

Example on land:
https://api.onwater.io/42.35,-71.1

```
{
  lat: 42.35,
  lon: -71.1,
  water: false
}
```

Since you're using JavaScript, here is an example jQuery snippet you might use:

```
function is_water_huh(lat, lon) {
  $.get( "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/" + lat + "," + lon, function( data ) {
    return data['water'];
  });
}

alert(is_water_huh(23.92323, -66.3));
```